# Solving a simple symbolic equation in python

Tags: python, sympy

I am using *sympy* to solve a very simple equation symbolically, but the solution I get for the variable is an empty matrix! Here is the code:

```
from sympy import *

x = Symbol('x')
l_x = Symbol('l_x')

x_min = -6
x_max = 6

precision_x = 10**8 

solve(((x_max-x_min)/((2**l_x)-1))/precision_x, l_x)

print(l_x)
```

I tried some other simple equations such as:

```
solve(x**2 = 4, x)
```

And the later works perfectly; I just do not understand why the former one does not work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is simple: your equation has no result.

The equation is `12/((2**l_x)-1))/1e8 = 0` and that has no solution.

See what `y = 12/((2**x)-1))/1e8` looks like ([copied from wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=12%2F((2**x)-1))%2F1e8)):

[image: y = 12/((2**x)-1))/1e8]

To compare, try solving e.g. `12/((2**l_x)-1))/1e8 = 1` instead:

```
>>> solve(((x_max-x_min)/((2**l_x)-1))/precision_x - 1, l_x)
[(-log(25000000) + log(25000003))/log(2)]
```

Works like a charm!

Comment: @Prateek What I wrote is a copy/paste from Python console. It prints without `print`. I thought that was obvious from the typical `>>>` prompt, but I guess not everyone likes the console as much as I do :)

Comment: @Prateek Actually, you added `-1` twice. It is difficult to read, but maybe this would be cleaner: `original_eq = ((x_max-x_min)/((2**l_x)-1))/precision_x`, and then `solve(original_eq - 1, l_x)`

Comment: yeah my bad. I thought brackets and then realized BODMAS works fine for your exp.. Mine and your result are same `(f(x))-1` vs `f(x)-1`  I was trying to ask you `(f(x))-1`

Comment: @zvone Ahh! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @zvone just one quick question; have any ideas why using 'sympy' and its commands (i.e. solve and symbol) gives me a warning in 'spyder' IDE? For the 'from sympy import *' it says: "'from sympy import *' used; unable to detect undefined names"! For the 'symbol' and 'solve' it says: "'symbol' may be undefined, or defined from star imports: sympy". The code still works, but I wonder why I get warnings, and if there is a way to get rid of the warnings?

Comment: @Antonio I don't use spyder, but I guess you would fix the problems by replacing `from sympy import *` with `from sympy import solve, Symbol`. It is generally a good idea to avoid `*` imports, so spyder may be complaining about that.

Comment: @zvone you’re awesome dude, thanks! I did what you said and it works without warnings :)

Answer (score 6):

The expression given to solve has an assumed rhs of `0` which no value of `l_x` can satisfy. Try something like this instead:

```
from sympy import *
q, r, s, t = symbols("q r s t")
eq = (q-r)/(2**s-1)/t
solve(eq-1,s)
```

The output is:

```
[log((q - r + t)/t)/log(2)]
```

to explicitly create an equation object with a non-zero rhs you can do something like:

```
solve(Eq(eq,1),s)
```